# Laravel 5 - Authentication with Login-Form (users) and API-Request (students)

Tags: laravel, api, authentication

I want to authenticate normal users (`users-table`) with login form and laravel auth.

Additionally I want to authenticate students (`students-table`) with API-request like:

`mylaravelsite.com/?studentkey=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&studentname=YYYYY`

How can I do this? I think with a middleware?

How can I use the `Auth` class to check if the logged in person is `user` or `student` or `guest`?

Answer (score 1):

I like to build applications in the following way:

- A route having a single purpose, meaning, one route is for authenticating users and another route is for authenticating students
- Validating data on the middleware before performing ANY operation

Now to your question:

If you really need, you can create different routes linked to the same authentication method, and create a middleware to each where you 'manipulate' run-type which class the Auth is going to be used

```
auth()->getProvider()->setModel(App\Student::class);
```

There are other ways to do this, depending on the way you wish to authenticate. If you want a more detailed explanation, give us a scenario to work on:

1. How the user authenticates vs how the student authenticates
2. What is going to differ from these 2 authentications and how its handled

Note: You're authenticating users with a HTTP request to a certain route, which is the same as your example link, except that you're giving an HTTPGET example and default is POST on authentication

Comment: 1. user authentificates with email and password with a form (POST Request). This is the standard Laravel auth class. A student gets an email with a link and can authenticate without write anything. The params studenkey and studentname are in the students table.

2. The user and student must get another roles after authenticate. They must see other pages.

Comment: Check documentation on JWT, should help you on your student part. It is basically some sort of generated key with a validation date, related to a student's identity